# Unable to register a device with MobileFirst and Swift client

Tags: swift, ibm-mobilefirst

I am testing with IBM MobileFirst sample code using a locally installed MFP server with a iOS client. I am expecting the following code with give me an error or a token.  However, they are both nil.

WLAuthorizationManager.sharedInstance().obtainAccessToken(forScope: nil) { (token, error) -> Void in

```
        if (error != nil) {
            self.titleLabel.text = "Bummer..."
            self.connectionStatusLabel.text = "Failed to connect to MobileFirst Server\n\(serverURL)"
            print("Did not recieve an access token from server: " + error.debugDescription)
        } else {
            self.titleLabel.text = "Yay!"
            self.connectionStatusLabel.text = "Connected to MobileFirst Server\n\(serverURL)"
            print("Recieved the following access token value: " + token!.value)
        }

        self.testServerButton.isEnabled = true
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you get in `error.debugDescription`?

Answer (score 0):

Things to look for:

1. That you're using the correct app version (if you registered via the Console)
2. That you're using the correct application identifier. The identifier is **case sensitive** and whether you register from CLI or Console, you need to make sure your enter it correctly
3. If you registered from the console, make sure you have added to your app the .plist file with the server details.